# Can anyone help me to use the enter key to execute this program?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, search-engine

I have created a small program that pulls from the YouTube API which allows you to search for a random video for whatever title you enter when prompted. I have it so everything is working except, I would like to be able to hit the enter key on the keyboard to run the search. I would assume that the fix is as simple as an onKeyDown event, but I have tried to implement it a few ways and it seems to break every time. I'm not sure if it is because the way I am calling my onClickListener or what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us your attempt at the `keydown` event? I'm not seeing it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it because it wasn't working. 'code' $("searchterm").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("search").click();
    }
});

Comment: You aren't accessing the items properly. You are missing the `#` (for *id*): `$("#searchterm")...` and `$("#search")...`

Comment: I just realized that. Thank you! I tried it both ways and it still didn't work. I believe my issue is hoisting.

Comment: You should probably take down that api key, I don't know if it's supposed to be the public key or private key but nonetheless I wouldn't bust it out for everyone to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#searchterm').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    search();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried that. It doesn't seem to be working. Is Hoisting a concern? I have it placed now under my search_term variable declaration.

Comment: You put it in the function. It needs to be outside the search function

Comment: Ahh... You are correct. Thank you for that. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Might want to take your API key down

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to generate a new one.